# Zend form change elements required options to false at runtime

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-file

I have a form and having two file upload elements. it is like

```
$data_file_one = $this->createElement('file','data_file_one');
            $data_file_one->setRequired(true)
                            ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'csv')
                            ->setDestination($filepath);
```

Both are set to required true. I use the same form for new post and edit posts. When it is used for editing the file upload should not be mandatory and must be set to required false. So, I need to change

> setRequired(true) to setRequired(false)

How can I do when edit action is called to load form and change this element option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zend_Forms have a method called getElement that allow you to retrieve an element from a form by its name. This gives you the ability to modify an element's default value before rendering it to the user.

For example, to change a field from being required to being optional, you can do the following:

```
$form->getElement('data_file_one')->setRequired(false);
```